# Labeling axis. Convertion from Excel. Convert data into String

Tags: excel, matlab, graph, axis-labels

How would you plot an A vs B graph,where A and B are columns in Excel such as

```
A   
Red
Green
Blue
```

and

```
B
1:00 AM
2:00 AM
3:00 AM
```

for 3*3 graphs I use

```
set(gca,'XTick',1:3);
set(gca,'XTickLabel',{'Red','Green','Blue'});
set(gca,'YTick',1:3);
set(gca,'YTickLabel',{'1:00 AM','2:00 AM','3:00 AM'});
```

However manual entering for 1000*1000 would be a mess.

So my **question** is:
**How do I convert values Red Green Blue from column A as `{'Red','Green','Blue'}`? (in order to use them in `set(gca,'XTickLabel'...)`**

I tried using

```
 color = xlsread(fileName, 'A1:A3');
```

but it didn't convert the data into the right format.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *second* output argument of `xlsread` contains text data. The first contains only numerical:

```
>> [nums,colors,raw] = xlsread('colorData.xlsx','A1:A3');
>> colors
colors = 
    'Red'
    'Green'
    'Blue'
```

UPDATE: The times read by `xlsread` are in Excel's serial date format (a numerical representation). They can be converted to a string with the time using `datestr`.

```
>> nums
nums =
    0.0417
    0.0833
    0.1250
>> datestr(nums)
ans =
 1:00 AM
 2:00 AM
 3:00 AM
```

These are actually dates, using [Jan. 1 1900 as time zero](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/import_export/when-to-convert-dates-from-excel-files.html). So, but giving just a time, it a number assuming this day. However, MATLAB uses Jan-1-0000, so if you have dates as well as times, convert them using `datestr(t + datenum('30-Dec-1899'))`, where `t` is the numerical value with the serial date number.

Comment: in order for that to work , I need to reformat everything to "text", is that correct?

Comment: There is a third output to xlsread which is the 'raw' data. It is a cell array which can contain both 'double', 'chars', etc. In your case it seems that they would all be chars (since '1:00 AM' contains non-numeric values) and so you should be able to use this cell array directly in your call to ticklabel.

Comment: it does extract them, however,
not in the '1:00 AM' format.
What it does it just gives me [1:00 AM] [2:00 AM] etc. Can that be easily converted into text?

Comment: @user3402959 Can you post a simple example xls(x) file somewhere?

Comment: @user3402959 Use `datestr(nums)` to convert into a date string, I believe.